# How to seelct all records in mysql using IN keyword in where cluase?

Tags: mysql

How to `select` all records in `mysql` using `IN` keyword in where clause?

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE LocationId IN ()
```

how to get all records

Comment: Specify the id in brackets

Comment: Hi @Dileep Kumar,

How to select all records? This statement is not clear enough to provide answer to this question.

Let everyone know if you want to select all records from which location to receive correct answer or guidance on problem you are working on.

Comment: What a strange request

Answer (score 0):

Pass all values in () like this

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE LocationId IN (1, 10,5)
```

Comment: Dilip Please try this